# Warning:Module version com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 depends on libraries but is a jar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

When I created a new project in Android Studio bundle it is displaying the following error:

> Warning:Module version com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 depends on libraries but is a jar
>   Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not find appcompat-v7.jar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/PRASOON SHARMA/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.jar

I am not sure where I have made the mistake.
Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.prasoonsharma.club"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen because of you use plus `+` on:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Gradle is confused to decide the location that will be used to compiling the library, i.e. in `file:/C:/Users/PRASOON SHARMA/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/` or in `file:/C:/Users/PRASOON SHARMA/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`. So, the gradle script should look like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Update Support Library to the latest version, and rebuild your project.

Comment: I found the solution by uninstalling and again installing the repository and library from sdk manager. Thanx for the help